# In RAPIDWEAVER: font awesome works in HTML stacks but not TEXT boxes

Tags: html

After watching the Joe Workman podcast describing how to enable Font Awesome on RapidWeaver Stacks pages, I went ahead and pasted the BootstrapCDM code (plus added "http:" as per Jow Workman) into the page header as per instructions.

PROBLEM: The code works in HTML stacks (I see the icon in preview mode), but not in TEXT stacks as per Joe Workman's examples (wherein you can change the alignment and size of the icon via font controls).

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you paste the code here?

Comment: Here is the code:
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Problem solved by Joe Workman tech support: There's an extra step - highlight the code that you placed in the text box, and go up to FORMAT>IGNORE FORMATTING.

All good.

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and not as a comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here - just realized this should be posted as an ANSWER:

Problem solved by Joe Workman tech support: There's an extra step - highlight the code that you placed in the text box, and go up to FORMAT>IGNORE FORMATTING. All good.